# Add text before price in WooCommerce on archive pages issue

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, price

I'm using the following code to add text before the price if the product is on sale on the archive pages in WooCommerce:

```php
function wps_custom_message() {
 
    $product = wc_get_product();
    if ( $product->is_on_sale() ) {
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'cw_change_product_price_display' );
        add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'cw_change_product_price_display' );
        function cw_change_product_price_display( $price ) {
            // Your additional text in a translatable string
            $text = __('<span>Your sale price is:</span><br>');

            // returning the text before the price
            return $text . ' ' . $price;
        }
    }
}
 
add_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description', 'wps_custom_message', 9 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_single_product', 'wps_custom_message', 9 );
```

But the text appears also on products where sale price is not set. 
What I'm doing wrong?

[image]

As you can see on the screenshot, the text shouldn't be on the products that haven't got sale price.

Comment: Those two filter callbacks you add there for `woocommerce_get_price_html` and `woocommerce_cart_item_price` _stay_ added, they will affect everything that gets processed afterwards within the current request.

Comment: What is the even point of hooking into `woocommerce_archive_description` and `woocommerce_before_single_product` here? Why are you not directly adding a filter function for `woocommerce_get_price_html` and `woocommerce_cart_item_price`, and _in there_ check if that current product is on sale or not?

Comment: If you want to limit this to archive and single product pages - then you should check the appropriate conditionals _inside_ your callback function, to determine if you are in one of those two contexts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `woocommerce_format_sale_price` filter. Have a look [at the docs](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-formatting-functions.html#source-view.1297).

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_sale_price', 'add_text_to_sales', 100, 3 );
function add_text_to_sales( $price, $regular_price, $sale_price ) {
    // Your additional text in a translatable string
    $text = __('<span>Your sale price is:</span><br>');
    
    return $text . $price;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To prepend a text to products on sale price, replace your code simply with the following:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'cw_change_product_price_display', 100, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'cw_change_product_price_display', 100, 2 );
function cw_change_product_price_display( $price_html, $mixed ) {
    $product = is_a($mixed, 'WC_product') ? $mixed : $mixed['data'];

    if ( $product->is_on_sale() ) {
        $price_html = sprintf('<span>%s:</span> <br>%s', __('Your sale price is', 'woocommerce'), $price_html);
    }
    return $price_html;
}
```

If you don't want to have this on cart items, remove:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_price', 'cw_change_product_price_display', 100, 2 );
```

If you want to have this only on WooCommerce archive pages, replace:

```php
if ( $product->is_on_sale() ) {
```

with:

```php
if ( ! is_product() && $product->is_on_sale() ) {
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, your code is also working, i choosed the first answer now.